# Is $( E^c)^o =(E^o)^c ?$ true/false

Tags: real-analysis

Given $X= \mathbb{R}$ and    $E \subset \mathbb{R}$

Now my question is that

Is $( E^c)^o =(E^o)^c ?$

where  $o$ denote the interior and $c$ denote the complement

I think this is not true

take $E= \emptyset$

Now $\emptyset^c= \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^0=\mathbb{R}$

This implies $( E^c)^o \neq (E^o)^c$

Comment: But also $\varnothing^o=\varnothing$ and $\varnothing^c=\mathbb R$, so they are the same, right?

Comment: What is $\emptyset ^o$

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah : $E^o$ is the largest open set contained in $E$, so $\varnothing^o = \varnothing$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general.

Consider $E = (0,1)$. Then $E^{c} = (-\infty,0]\cup[1,+\infty)$.

Hence $\text{int}(E^{c}) = (-\infty,0)\cup(1,+\infty)$ and $(\text{int}(E))^{c} = (-\infty,0]\cup[1,+\infty)$.

Hopefully this helps.